# Open Facebook profile with app scoped id of user

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My app uses Facebook SDK and I have **app scoped id** of another Facebook user.
I want to be able to:
a) Open the Facebook App to that user's profile.
b) Open a WebView to the user's profile.

What I tried:  The various custom URL schemes with intents. None gives a decent result.

What were the results:
a) Facebook app doesn't like app scoped user ids so it either opens an error page('Content not available') or in other cases opens always to my profile page although I am sure I post id of a completely different user.

b) In case of WebView I try to load this url https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/[APP_SCOPED_USER_ID_HERE]/
but it requires me to log in before redirecting me to the required page which totally ruins the feature I am trying to implement - the user already logged in with facebook in my app and I do have the access token.

Answer (score 1):

**finally it's work for me:**

```
try {
Intent followIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" +
                        "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/"+<scoped user id>+"/"));
                activity.startActivity(followIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/" + <user name>)));
                String errorMessage = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "Message is empty" : e.getMessage();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it´s not possible to use the profile link when the user is not logged in - although, the user does not have to be logged in with HIS account, he just needs to be logged in with any Facebook account.

There was recently a discussion about the "Content not available" error message in the developers group on Facebook, if that happens for one of your profile, you could try opening a bug. If it´s not a bug, at least you should get an answer what´s wrong.

Comment: So although my application logged in a given user with Facebook, he can't open other people's profiles neither in the Facebook app, nor in the browser provided he has their app scoped id? That doesn't make sense to me but seems to be true for now.

Comment: as you can read in my answer, it SHOULD work if a user is logged in. if that error appears, try filing a bug.

Comment: A bug has been filed a long time ago https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332195860270199 I am searching for a workaround. It just seems strange that this won't work.

Comment: well, there is no workaround, i´m afraid. at least not that i know of.